# Check if user has selected a date with the Datepicker widget in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I have created a separate activity in my app for inserting data into sqlite database where there is a date button whose Onclickfunction pops up the date picker widget,
So before inserting the tuple into database,i am checking for empty fields
Now i want to know how do i check if the user has selected a date or left it empty?

I tried to find existing functions like isset() but no such function exists....

Language used is java on Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: What you have try.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

Comment: @ShreeKhanal i wanted for Android studio

Comment: The IDE is **not relevant**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener`

```
Boolean isDateChanged = false;

private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateSetListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
           isDateChanged = true;
    }     
 };
```

Comment: but will it work if the user doesnt select a date and wants to use default value?

Comment: So what you want?